# Unable to connect to MariaDB using DBeaver

Tags: mysql, database, ubuntu, mariadb, dbeaver

I just installed MariaDB 10.1.29 on Ubuntu 18.04. From the command line I can connect using sudo:

```
sudo mysql -u root -p
```

But not without sudo.

Also, if I try to connect to the database through [DBeaver](https://dbeaver.io/), I get:

```
Could not connect: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
```

While the credentials are correct. I tried installing MySQL 5.7, but I'm experiencing the exact same issue there as well.

What am I missing?

Comment: same problem. Didn't find out how to establish a sudo connection in DBeaver

Comment: I didn't find a solution yet. The problem only exits with the `root` user. In the meantime I created an additional user using the cli and granted permissions on all tables. So now I can manage those databases with the additional user. Hope that helps.

Comment: Did you also notice that if you login using `sudo mysql -u root -p` you can write whatever you want for password and it works! And this is why also this works `sudo mysql -u root`... This is a big security issue if you ask me...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As it turns out, this is expected behaviour for MariaDB and MySQL. To overcome the issue, it is advisable to create a separate user and grant access to all databases created. Here is a step by step guide on how to create databases using the command line and grant permissions to the user of your choice.

#### Log in to MariaDB/MySQL

```
$ sudo mysql -u root -p
```

#### Create a database

```
mysql> CREATE DATABASE `database_name`;
```

#### Create a user

```
mysql> CREATE USER 'user_name' IDENTIFIED BY 'a_secure_password';
```

#### Grant user permissions

```
mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON database_name.* TO 'user_name'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

#### Apply changes

```
mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Comment: This worked for me after struggling for a long time. @wout Please mark your answer as the solution.

Comment: @Dawoodjee Great to hear I could help. I did not know I could mark my own answer as the solution ;)

Comment: Hi, How do I follow these steps when I already have a existing database? Please let me know. Thanks & Best Regards Michael

Comment: For me the command to grant permission failed. So - `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'user'@'localhost' identified by 'password';` worked

Comment: Also, % != localhost so you need to have `'user'@'localhost'`