# Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' in dbeaver

Tags: mysql, database, ubuntu, dbeaver

When I do a test connection in DBeaver in Ubuntu 18.04, I get an error:

> Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'

I do not understand how to solve this. I can connect to mysql in terminal by `sudo mysql`.

[image]

I have also left the database field empty.

Comment: Do you have a password set for the root user? Is that the complete text of the error message you are getting?

Comment: @Dave I am able to run this `sudo mysql` . this is the full error message.

Comment: refer to the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50453078/unable-to-connect-to-mariadb-using-dbeaver

Answer (score 3):

Experienced a similar issue. Maybe this advice will help you to solve the error. Your user’s password should not contain any special characters.
In my case, ’~’ in password was the whole reason of problem.

Comment: Thanks this helped me, I couldn't understand what I am doing wrongly. I had password with `<!]` and removing this resolved my issue

Answer (score 3):

If this problem keeps happening to someone, the reason is that Ubuntu, Mint (and other distros) they no longer come with a 'blank' password for default.
So, we need to reset it:

```
sudo mysql_secure_installation
```

Select the password level you want, write it and then yes (Y) to all. Then:

```
sudo mysql
```

And execute (change the word password with the password you have written before):

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password';
```

That's all, now you can configure local DB in DBeaver with the new password. Hope this works for you.

Answer (score 2):

It works with Mariadb too. You must check the syntax of step 3, in MariaDB is:

```sql
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED VIA mysql_native_password USING PASSWORD('password');
```

Thanks *@gasgen*.

If this problem keeps happening to someone, the reason is that Ubuntu Mint (and other distros) no longer come with a 'blank' password by default. So, we need to reset it:

```
sudo mysql_secure_installation
```

Select the password level you want, write it, and then yes (Y) to all.
Then:

```
 sudo mysql
```

And execute (change the word password with the password you have written before):

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password';
```

That's all, now you can configure local DB in DBeaver with the new password. Hope this works for you.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with Dbeaver (and with Beekeeper Studio also). It helped me to change the password to the empy password. That should be default configuration, but it seems, the empty password is stored like invalid value in the database...

Login to the database via terminal:

```bash
sudo mysql -u root
```

- Enter password for `sudo`, not for database account...

Check user system table:

```sql
SELECT host, user, password FROM mysql.user;
```

If the password for your root account is `invalid` (or whatever else than empty cell), then set the empty password again:

```sql
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '';
exit;
```

Now try to login via Dbeaver with root account and password leave empty.

The solution above worked for both of the DBeaver and Beekeeper.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with MariaDb and Dbeaver on Ubuntu. Yes, you need to set the password again for the root user and then it works.

Saludos,
Michael

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35727850)